# How to bypass permission denied error?

Tags: windows, r, shapefile

The following example writes a point shapefile to disc.  However, I get an error when the script tries to write a shapefile to C:/.  I am able to write to a external hard drive though (G:/).  The following is the error I receive in R:

> Error in file(out.name, "wb") : cannot open the connection In
>   addition: Warning message: In file(out.name, "wb") : cannot open file
>   'c:/test.shp': Permission denied

**How can I bypass or resolve this error?**

```
# available from: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shapefiles/shapefiles.pdf
# Samples of using the convert.to.shapefile function to write out simple shapefiles
# from basic R data.frames

require(shapefiles)
require(maptools)

dd <- data.frame(Id=c(1,2),X=c(3,5),Y=c(9,6))
ddTable <- data.frame(Id=c(1,2),Name=c("Item1","Item2"))
ddShapefile <- convert.to.shapefile(dd, ddTable, "Id", 1)
write.shapefile(ddShapefile, "C:/test", arcgis=T)
shape <- readShapePoints("C:/test")
plot(shape)
```

Comment: is this an R question or a Windows question?  Do you otherwise have write access to the root directory of the C: drive?

Comment: It's a Windows question.  Probably UAC preventing the modification of the root-level directory.

Comment: I've added a windows tag.  I'm not sure what the root cause of this error is.

Comment: if as I suspect `writeLines(c("a","b"),con="C:/test.txt")` fails with the same error, perhaps you would consider revising your question (as in that case the root of the problem would have absolutely nothing to do with the shapefile package)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer, do not write to the root-level directory of the system volume.

There are a few good reasons to create files/directories at the root of `C:`, but this isn't one of them.  Use `C:/Temp/test` instead.